# _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'CustomerElement')

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am testing API workflow using flutter to get familiar with it.

The card widget below is wrapped in an obx widget to build the cards using data from the api

I am getting this error at code:

```
return CardList(customer: customerController.customerList[index];



Exception has occurred:
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'CustomerElement')
```

vscode in debug mode I can see that `customerList` has the json information to it.

I feel the problem is coming from the model in flutter. I am not sure.

I am using a database from my localhost for the API source. More below.

Json response:

```
[
    [
        {
            "customer_id": 1,
            "customer_title": "m",
            "customer_fname": "john",
            "customer_lname": "doe",
            "customer_email": "johndoe@mail.com",
            "customer_password": "john"
        },
        {
            "customer_id": 2,
            "customer_title": "f",
            "customer_fname": "jane",
            "customer_lname": "doe",
            "customer_email": "jane@female.com",
            "customer_password": "jane1234"
        }
    ],
    {
        "fieldCount": 0,
        "affectedRows": 0,
        "insertId": 0,
        "serverStatus": 34,
        "warningCount": 0,
        "message": "",
        "protocol41": true,
        "changedRows": 0
    }
]
```

Flutter model generated from quicktype.io:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final customer = customerFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<dynamic> customerFromJson(String str) => List<dynamic>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => x));

String customerToJson(List<dynamic> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x)));

class CustomerElement {
    CustomerElement({
       required this.customerId,
       required this.customerTitle,
       required this.customerFname,
       required this.customerLname,
       required this.customerEmail,
       required this.customerPassword,
    });

    int customerId;
    String customerTitle;
    String customerFname;
    String customerLname;
    String customerEmail;
    String customerPassword;

    factory CustomerElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CustomerElement(
        customerId: json["customer_id"],
        customerTitle: json["customer_title"],
        customerFname: json["customer_fname"],
        customerLname: json["customer_lname"],
        customerEmail: json["customer_email"],
        customerPassword: json["customer_password"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "customer_id": customerId,
        "customer_title": customerTitle,
        "customer_fname": customerFname,
        "customer_lname": customerLname,
        "customer_email": customerEmail,
        "customer_password": customerPassword,
    };
}

class PurpleCustomer {
    PurpleCustomer({
      required this.fieldCount,
      required this.affectedRows,
      required this.insertId,
      required this.serverStatus,
      required this.warningCount,
      required this.message,
      required this.protocol41,
      required this.changedRows,
    });

    int fieldCount;
    int affectedRows;
    int insertId;
    int serverStatus;
    int warningCount;
    String message;
    bool protocol41;
    int changedRows;

    factory PurpleCustomer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PurpleCustomer(
        fieldCount: json["fieldCount"],
        affectedRows: json["affectedRows"],
        insertId: json["insertId"],
        serverStatus: json["serverStatus"],
        warningCount: json["warningCount"],
        message: json["message"],
        protocol41: json["protocol41"],
        changedRows: json["changedRows"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "fieldCount": fieldCount,
        "affectedRows": affectedRows,
        "insertId": insertId,
        "serverStatus": serverStatus,
        "warningCount": warningCount,
        "message": message,
        "protocol41": protocol41,
        "changedRows": changedRows,
    };
}
```

The following on converting the http request

```
class RemoteService {
  static var client = http.Client();

  static Future<List<dynamic>?> fetchCustomer() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/test/getcustomer');

    var response = await client.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = response.body;
      return customerFromJson(jsonString);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your `Json response:`  fixed like this? Also can you include how you are converting the response on http

Comment: I'm getting this response from a stored procedure on MySQL. I'm using NodeJS as a backend to handle all my API.

Comment: The problem is with the json response itself then?

Comment: Yes, I don't like this format, you can include key before item and list, so It will be map rather than List<dynamic>

Comment: Can you specify where I can add the changes? I can provide more info if you'd like.

Comment: It can be {"modelA": [], "params":{}} I think

Comment: You were right. The problem was with the Json response. the stored procedure was sending an OK_packet. I did the query directly from the backend and it was all good.